# $_POST data to .config file but run output file

Tags: php, html

I have a script from GitHub what i modified to what i want. Normal use would be to put data in text. I want to get data from input form.

Normally if the file gets made i wouldn't mind to keep it simple, but the file doesn't get written right because data inst getting stored and used.
and the output of run show that the sites i connect with curl has accepted the data

the issue is what i have tried $_POST en $session to get the data in the file 
but i cant seem to make it work a long next to each other.

also tried as my script shows work with 2 forms.

```
<?php
// config.php file
 session_start();

$_SESSION['url'] = $_POST['Url'];

$site = ($_SESSION['url']); // this is the input data
```

```
<?php
// run.php (file or where i want the output of)
 session_start();

$_SESSION['url'] = $_POST['Url'];
require_once( 'config.php' ); // in my file it was already there (edit to reply barmar)
///////////
$real_site = domain_root($site);

if ($real_site != $site){
    logger("Reformatted site from $site to $real_site", 2);
}
```

```
<?php
// input.html (the screen user going to use for input) 
session_start();

$_SESSION['url'] = $_POST['Url'];


?>
     <html>
        <form action="config.php" method="POST">
         URL:<br>
  <input type="text"  name="Url" value="" placeholder="https://www.example.com/">
  <br></form>
  <form action="run.php">
            <input type="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

hope there is a way to send data to .config and that run file can use that data

Comment: Where is your code that tries to use the config file? We'll help you fix the it, we won't write it for you.

Comment: You can use `file_put_contents()` to write to a file, and `file_get_contents()` to read from it.

Comment: @barmar i edit the script but was included in the original i have here. 

And tried file_put_contents(); but when i place // header("location:run.php"); i get error to many redirects

so that doesnt work for me at this moment

Comment: Which file is `config.php`, which is `run.php`

Comment: If you're creating config.php dynamically from the POST parameters, where is the code that does this?

Comment: @barmar i wrote on top what file was what, but to make it more clear i have put .php behind it.  $site is the only data/value that needs to be handled by the user input

so in the input.html user write the input 

then that needs to be send to config.php

but run.php uses just $site to make it work 

and run.php have to output thats need to be show on screen. 

So what i would like is $_POST["Url"] to config but execute run.php

Answer (score 0):

OKAY, what i did wrong was the use of $_SESSION

for others who get value array() or no output.

You dont have to use session_start(); at the start file where you want to collect the data from/of (so the page where your form is written) only on the pages that you want to use the $_POST or $_Get values.

Or atleast this works for me, and from there you can use it as a get or post method